# Inversion algorithm for band matrices

Tags: matrices

Is there a clever way to invert a matrix with non-zero values only on the first  diagonals :

As an example, a matrix like this (3 diagonals have real $v_{ij}$ values, others are zero) :
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
v_{1,1}  & v_{1,2}     &  0      &   0&  \cdots   &\cdots  & 0  \\
v_{2,1}  & v_{2,2} & v_{2,3} & 0 &        & & \vdots \\
0 & v_{3,2} & v_{3,3} & v_{3,4} & \ddots &  & \vdots  \\
0& 0 & v_{4,3} & v_{4,4}& \ddots & 0 &0 \\ 
\vdots   &  & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots  & v_{n-2, n-1}& 0  \\
\vdots  &        &  & 0 & v_{n-1, n-2} & v_{n-1,n-1}& v_{n-1, n} \\
0 & \cdots  & \cdots     & \cdots & 0    & v_{n, n-1}      & v_{n,n}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I am looking for an algorithm that will be faster than the $O(n^3)$ Gauss algorithm, taking into account the specificity of the matrix.

---

EDIT :

To be more precise I am looking for an algorithm that solves a linear system which matrix has more than 3 diagonals (the matrix above is just an example).

Comment: See (http://www.math.hkbu.edu.hk/ICM/LecturesAndSeminars/08OctMaterials/1/Slide3.pdf)

Comment: Yes, this is a standard topic in numerical linear algebra. It's discussed in Golub and Van Loan, for example.

Comment: @littleO : Thanks for your comment, I have worked out an algorithm with the help of your citation

Comment: Thanks also @JeanMarie for editing the title, it helped me for my searches on the web :)

Answer (score 2):

Thomas's algorithm can be used to solve systems of equations with matrices of this form in $O(n)$ time.  You can use it repeatedly with right hand sides given by the columns of the identity matrix to get $A^{-1}$ is $O(n^{2})$ time.

However, you probably don't actually need or want $A^{-1}$.  In most situations you need to compute $A^{-1}v$ for various vectors $v$.  This can be accomplished more quickly by using Thomas's algorithm to solve $Ax=v$ as needed.

Comment: Tanks for you answer. Yes, I do not need the invert of the matrix, so I have use LU decomposition to solve the problem.